# Assigning turtle commands to variables and recalling them on python

Tags: python, variables, turtle-graphics

I'm wanting to assign turtle commands as such:

```
F = turt.forward(30)
+ = turt.left(90)
- = turt.right(90)
```

however it won't let me assign these commands to the + and -, I don't want this to execute the commands. I also don't know how to execute them though. I want to use these variables to then right something like "F+F-F++FF"

```
import turtle
f = turt.forward(30)
+ = turt.left(90)
- = turt.right(90)
F+F-F-FF+F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to define some functions that we will use to define the operations of your turtle object:

```
def forward():
    turt.forward(30)

def left():
    turt.left(90)

def right():
    turt.right(90)
```

Next, we need to create a dictionary mapping the string keys to the functions that we had just defined:

```
map = {'F': forward, '+': left, '-'; right} # F will cause the turtle to go forward by 30
```

Lasty, we have to iterate over a sequence of strings in order to call functions according to this map:

```
for command in 'F+F-F++FF':
   map[command]()
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about using dictionaries. That works perfectly.